# Rename columns and create new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have doubt, because i changed name columns in my two dataframe

```
df1.rename(columns={'polarity':'polarityBiden','Sentiment_Type':'TextblobBiden','compound':'compoundBiden','sentiment_type':'VaderBiden','score':'scoreBayenBiden'})
```

And i get output:

```
polarityBiden   subjectivity    TextblobBiden   compoundBiden   VaderBiden  scoreBayenBiden
0   0.000000    0.047619    NEUTRAL -0.3818 NEGATIVE    Negative
```

And for second it's same but when i would like concat two df with code ;

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join="inner")
result
```

All is back to prev. version

```
polarity    subjectivity    Sentiment_Type  compound    sentiment_type  score   polarity    subjectivity    Sentiment_Type  compound    sentiment_type  score
0   0.000000    0.047619    NEUTRAL -0.3818 NEGATIVE    Negative    0.160000    0.466667    POSITIVE    -0.6705 NEGATIVE
```

How to linked two df with new name columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) function creates a copy of the dataframe instead of rename based on the original dataframe.  You have to either reassign it to the original name or use the `inplace=True` parameter to force it work on the original dataframe instead of on the copy.

You can do it like below (re-assign) :

```
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'polarity':'polarityBiden','Sentiment_Type':'TextblobBiden','compound':'compoundBiden','sentiment_type':'VaderBiden','score':'scoreBayenBiden'})
```

or using `inplace=True`:

```
df1.rename(columns={'polarity':'polarityBiden','Sentiment_Type':'TextblobBiden','compound':'compoundBiden','sentiment_type':'VaderBiden','score':'scoreBayenBiden'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rename `df2` columns before `concat`

```
df2.columns = df1.columns
```

You can also concatenate both dataframes with vstack from numpy and convert the resulting ndarray to dataframe:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df1, df2]), columns=df1.columns)
```

`numpy.vstack()` function is used to stack the sequence of input arrays vertically to make a single array.